# Converting an integer to a character array i.e. 123 => '123'

Tags: c, casting, malloc

The aim of this code is to convert an integer into a character array.
The following code results in garbage output. It seems to be right, though. Any suggestions?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char* intToChar(int product);

int main()
{   
    printf("%s\n", intToChar(213));

    return 0;
}

char* intToChar(int product)
{
    int temp = product;
    int c = 0;
    char* morphed;

    while(temp)
    {
        temp /= 10;
        c++;
    }
    /printf("c : %d\n", c);//db
    morphed = malloc(sizeof(char) * c);

    temp = product;
//  printf("temp : %d\n", temp);//db
    c -= 1;
    while(temp)
    {
        morphed[c] = (char)temp % 10;
        //printf("c[] %c\n", morphed[c]);//db
        c -= 1;
        temp /= 10;
    }

    return morphed;
}
```

Comment: You need to add `'0'` to each digit in the output to get the digit `'0'` not the character with the value 0.

Comment: You have a memory leak. And *undefined behavior* as you don't terminate the "string". And is there a reason you have to make your own function instead of just using one of the `printf` functions (like using `printf` directly, of `snprinf` if you need a string)?

Comment: You need to add the null terminating character `'\0'` at the end of the string to use `printf()`. Do not forget to malloc the space for it ! `morphed = malloc(sizeof(char) * (c+1));morphed[c]='\0';`

Comment: Adding '0' did the trick!
Thank you!

Comment: The output is still not correct. int temp = 3 does not mean that  (char)temp  is equal to '3'.

Answer (score 1):

For starters take into account that 0 is a valid integer number that also should be converted to a string.

Also objects of type `int` can be negative.

And you need to convert each digit of a number to its character representation.

The resulted string shall be appended with the terminating zero.

The function can look as it is shown in the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * intToChar( int product )
{
    const int Base = 10;

    int temp = product;
    int n = 0;
    char* morphed;

    do { ++n; } while ( temp /= Base );

    if ( product < 0 ) ++n;

    morphed = malloc( ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );

    morphed[n--] = '\0';

    temp = product;

    do { morphed[n--] = '0' + abs( temp % Base ); } while ( temp /= Base );

    if ( product < 0 ) morphed[n] = '-';

    return morphed;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char *p;

    p = intToChar( 0 );

    puts( p );

    free( p );

    p = intToChar( 123 );

    puts( p );

    free( p );

    p = intToChar( -123 );

    puts( p );

    free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0
123
-123
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you basically want to convert an integer to a character array, or string. I do not see the reason of you creating your own function to do so. You can just use [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
int a = 213;
char str [20];
sprintf (str, "%d", a);
```

You can also use `snprintf`, which is safer.

---

As [@FUZxxi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417501/fuzxxl), adding a zero to each digit in the output will work.

Answer (score 0):

The following amendments

```
morphed = malloc(sizeof(char) * (1+c) ); /* leave room for a '\0' at end */
memset( morphed, 0, sizeof(char) *(1+c) ); /* set to 0.*/
```

and later

```
morphed[c] = (char)temp % 10 + '0';
```

This adds the ascii '0' value to each digit you have calculated

```
the digit '0' is ascii 48
the digit '1' is ascii 49
...
the digit '9' is ascii 57
```

For other character sets ...

```
char digits[] = "01234567890";
...
morphed[c] = digits[ temp % 10];
```